# How to calibrate a lens with wide fov and low F number

Tags: calibration

To calibrate a wide fov lens either a calibration board should be large or bring the calibration board closer to the lens. As making a large calibration board is expensive, I usually prefer the second solution but making a short distance does not work for a lens with low F number(e.g F1.2). Simply, the image will be out focused.

Does anyone know an open source calibration program for this situation?

For example, multiple small calibration boards can be used instead of a large single board. Which open source support it?

Comment: Could you use a brick wall? Bricks are of a uniform dimension and the courses should all be level.

Comment: Sounds like that is one of the few options I have now.